# Which one should I use?

Tags: grammar

Is

> What she does in her room?

grammatically correct? Or should I change it to:

> What does she do in her room?

Answer (score 2):

In direct questions in English, we usually invert the verb and the subject (which requires *do*-support for most verbs).

So statement:

> She does

Question:

> What does she do?

Answer (score 0):

What she does is in her room ? is not a question in  any circumstances. so it is not grammatically correct.

> **What does she do her in her room?**
>   Direct question.
>
> **What has she done in her room?**

The structure of a direct question is like this:

Wh-word+ helping verb + subject+ main verb in the base form/past participle+ (obect)+ adverbial/ prepositional phrase  etc'

> **I know what she does in her room**

Statement.

> **Do you know what she does in her room?**

Indirect question.

In the Indirect question  the structure is like that of a statement and the inversion of the helping verb is not needed for the second part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

"What she does in her room" is not a question even with a ? mark. It is a dependent noun clause. I don't know what she does in her room, or, What she does in her room is not known to me.

What does she do in her room? - is the question.